# Filling in a shape drawn by two turtles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I fill in this shape I drew?

Here's the code:

```py
t = turtle.Turtle()

t2 = t.clone()

#the shapes do not go beyond the screen

for count in range(2):
   
    t.circle(100, 180)
    t.right(180)

t2.circle(200, 180)
```

Answer (score 1):

set `t.color(turtle.bgcolor())`

start `begin_fill` on first `t2` and then `t`

draw

`end_fill` `t2` first

and then `end_fill` `t`

Entire code:

```py
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Turtle(); t2 = t.clone()
>>> t.color(turtle.bgcolor())
>>> t2.begin_fill(); t.begin_fill()
>>> t2.circle(200, 180)
>>> for count in range(2):
    t.circle(100, 180)
    t.right(180)

>>> t2.end_fill(); t.end_fill()
```

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to draw the shape with a single turtle to simplify the problem:

```
import turtle

turtle.begin_fill()

turtle.circle(100, 180)
turtle.circle(200, -180)
turtle.circle(100, 180)

turtle.end_fill()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

The approach of @Superior is perfectly valid (+1), but I'd code it differently:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

t1 = Turtle()

t1.begin_fill()
t1.circle(200, 180)
t1.end_fill()

t2 = Turtle()
t2.color(screen.bgcolor())

t2.begin_fill()

for _ in range(2):
    t2.circle(100, 180)
    t2.right(180)

t2.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```

The above can also be done just as easy with a single turtle.  And finally, for completeness, we could draw this figure via *stamping*, which we can do with one or more turtles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

t1 = Turtle()
t1.hideturtle()
t1.shape('circle')
t1.penup()

t1.shapesize(20)
t1.stamp()

t1.color(screen.bgcolor())
t1.shapesize(stretch_len=10)

t2 = t1.clone()
t2.shapesize(stretch_wid=10)

for sign in (-1, 1):
    t2.sety(sign * 100)
    t2.stamp()

t1.shape('square')
t1.backward(100)
t1.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Generally, I wouldn't `clone()` turtles unless there's some feature set on the original turtle that you want to preserve in the clone.  In your code, you clone a brand new turtle which has no benefit over creating a new turtle instance.  In the stamping example above, cloning is used to preserve the color and stretch-width of the original turtle before the original turtle itself changes.